# In python, How to form a 3*3 matrix from a given 4*4 matrix

Tags: python, matrix, logic

How to form a 3 cross 3 matrix from a given 4 cross 4 matrix
Need to output the number of such matrices we can form and the matrix itself.

Input:
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13

Could anyone help me with this was trying it for a long time.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Found the different numbers which are there in the given matrix along with the number of occurrences. Then tried using permutations and combinations to find the number of possibilities.

Comment: Include the code from which you are having errors.

Comment: And please provide the expected output too. Just to be clear.

Comment: Seems that you're looking for a `reshape` function?  Please share your attempts and confirm the output format.

Answer (score 0):

There are four matrices possible here. Think of it as if you are solving it with pen & paper. Just use iterations to achieve what you want. No need of permutations here. Take care of the boundary conditions in your iteration.